# Xamarin.Forms Activity indicator always in the cernter of the device screen

Tags: xamarin.forms, activity-indicator

how is possible to get the activity indicator always in the center of the screen independently if the page starts with a ScrollView or StackLayout or RelativeLayout ?
When for example I have a Scrollview page, the activity indicator is scrolling together with the content, and therefore in some cases no longer visible, but I would like to get it always on the center of the screen, doesn't matter if I have scrolled the content or not.

Thank you in advance for any help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to you to use this library that can visualize a loading image in the center of the screen

[Allan Ritchie UserDialogs](https://github.com/aritchie/userdialogs)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. There is no way to do it easily in Xamarin.Forms without adding another plug-in ?

Comment: @Stefano I don't know, sorry. You use always the plugin because it's very simple and works fine. Could it depend by the layout?

Comment: Yes, my problem is when I have a scroll view with inside a relatve layout container: the activity indicator which I place in the center it's in the center of the page which is bigger than screen device (for this reason it's a scroll view page), and when you scroll you loose the activity indicator because goes out of the screen.

Comment: I think there is the link on GitHub https://github.com/aritchie/userdialogs/blob/master/readme.md

Comment: Ok, I try the plugin, but when I try to install it from Nuge I get conflicts: Acr.UserDialogs requires Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 (>= 23.1.1), but when I try to update Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 to 23.1.1 I get conflicts with Xamarin.Forms 2.1.0.6529 which requires Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 (= 23.0.1.3). How can I do it ?

Comment: I've found the way installing version Acr.UserDialogs v.4.2.1

Comment: I implement this and woking fine. But how i can show and hide the same in a viewmodel?